# Should I Create a New Delegate Instance?

Tags: c#, delegates

What are the implications of doing this...

```
this.myButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.myButton_Clicked);
```

...versus this?

```
this.myButton.Click += this.myButton_Clicked;
```

I suspect that the compiler is creating a new instance for me in the second example. I'm sure this is a bit of a newbie question, but Google didn't turn up anything. Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: Good question is why does Visual Studio IntelliSense, even 2010, use the old syntax?!

Comment: Ten years later, most of the examples in Microsoft's documentation still do it the old way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2nd syntax is a shortcut for the 1st one introduced in C# 2.0.

http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3103031/Working-with-Delegates-Made-Easier-with-C-20.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second version makes the compiler create an implicit delegate, much like you can specify `this.MyMethod` instead of `new Action(this.MyMethod)` or `new Action(() => this.MyMethod())`.