# C#: what's the difference between SomeEvent += Method and SomeEvent += new Delegate(Method)

Tags: c#, events, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I Create a New Delegate Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585793/should-i-create-a-new-delegate-instance)

Hi, I've tried searching for the answer to this, but don't really know what terms to search for, and none of the site-suggested questions are relevant.  I'm sure this must have been answered before though.

Basically, can somebody tell me what's the difference between these two lines in C#:

```
SomeEvent += SomeMethod
SomeEvent += new SomeDelegate(SomeMethod)
```

For example:

```
DataContextChanged += App_DataContextChanged;
DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(App_DataContextChanged);
```

They both seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the same. The second variant is just a shorthand for the first called `Method group conversion`.

Simply put, the compiler infers what the type of the delegate is by using the delegate type of the event itself. This was introduced in C#2.0 if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

they do the same thing. The variation

```
SomeEvent += new SomeDelegate(SomeMethod)
```

was the only way to write it in C# 1.0, 1.1 . Since 2.0 you can write the other alternative as a simplification.

Answer (score 3):

Both are same.

```
SomeEvent += new SomeDelegate(SomeMethod)
```

mentions what happens under the hood i.e SomeDelegate constructor is called to create a instance of the object.