# What's the difference between a delegate creation expression and a method group conversion?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I was wondering what the difference was between

```
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
```

and

```
button.Click += button_Click;
```

I've seen both and generally use the 2nd version, but I was wondering what the difference was and when to use one over the other.

Comment: Quick note on the title - it's not referencing the *event* directly - it's just applying a *method group conversion* directly instead of using a delegate creation expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I Create a New Delegate Instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585793/should-i-create-a-new-delegate-instance)

Comment: @Jon: Feel free to change the title, I wasn't sure what to put there :)

Comment: @Rachel: I've changed it to something which is accurate, but probably wouldn't be something you'd have come up with... if you can think of anything more *useful* but still accurate-sounding, that would be good :)

Comment: @Jon: lol I would have never thought up a title like that.... makes sense though even if it took me a minute to understand what it said.

Comment: @Fredrik: Yes it's a duplicate but I couldn't find anything referencing my question before asking. Probably because I was looking for Events, not Delegates. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference, other than the first is valid in C# 1 and the second isn't.

There's a difference in terms of *just the RHS expression*, on the other hand. For example:

```
Delegate valid = new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
Delegate invalid = button_Click;
```

In the latter case the compiler doesn't know which delegate you want to convert the method group into, so you'll get a compile-time failure.

Comment: Furthermore, it's almost certain that you don't need to worry about C# 1.

Comment: @Tim: Except that it's useful to know why you may have code which takes the long-winded approach :)

Comment: Thanks! I only recently started using C# so wasn't even aware there was a C# 1